# Analysis of first order RC using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I finished designing the given circuit using Matlab but I am getting some weird output results on oscilloscope.

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here is what I did
[image]

I used the commands to define the R, F , C, and everything else, then I used Simulink to design and simulate. should not the output be some sinusoidal waveform ?
could you please help me out on this? 
it is asking for the gain? how do I find the gain from this oscilloscope output ?

Comment: If your frequency f is 250 Hz and the time scale in the oscilloscope plot is in seconds the result could be right. Have you tried zooming in? Your cutoff frequency is \$ f_c = \frac{1}{2 \pi R C} = 1061.03 Hz \$, and you are injecting a 250 Hz signal, so it should not be attenuated very much at all.

Comment: so how do I figure out the gain from this ?

Comment: Gain is V2/V1. You know V2. You know V1.

Comment: yes I know that, but based on the graph which one is V1 and v2?

Comment: or maybe because of Mux I put there, it is only showing V2? what does the Mux do in this circuit? I know it is a switch, but why do we use it here?

Comment: My guess is that the mux is there so that the "oscilloscope" can display both V1 and V2. I'm not sure but I think V1 and V2 might both be displayed in the plot - V1 is the yellow waveform and V2 is the pink one. If that's the case, V1's amplitude is simply 1.